# Ember: Binding properties in partial-templates of components

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Ive got a component which has two partial-templates. In these templates Im using properties of the JS-Backend like `{{myVar}}`. When updating this variable in my JS (`this.set('myVar', 'newValue');`) the template (the partial) wont update like it is not bindet to that property in the browsers HTML.

When accessing the property in the "main" *template.hbs* of my component, it works fine.

Could it be that ember wont bind the helpers in the partial templates like it does in normal templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, partials share the same scope and context as the component they are rendered within - [look at the guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper).

I used partials multiple times with bindings shared between component and nested partials. If you still have problems with these bindings I advice you to use components instead of partials. The migration won't be hard (couple of lines of code).

Comment: Aha okay. I found out that the problem isn't the fact, im using partials but using the same component twice. Only the first '{{myVar}}' works properly using binding. The second one won't get updated.

Comment: That's anoter case. Please open new question and remember about code excerpt as I do not exactly understand what you mean :) It will be best to have JSbin!